# mail() sent from address

Tags: email, ubuntu

How can I change the default from address for the php mail() function.  I know I can do it on a per-send basis, but I'd like to change the default setting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that in php.ini with "sendmail_from".

From the php.ini:

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

If you haven't got access to php.ini for some reason, you could set the following in a .htaccess file:

```
php_value sendmail_from you@example.com
```

Note: you can't set sendmail_path in this way for security reasons.
Source: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for our webmasters in the MTA (smtp server). If your MTA is postfix, you could use the sender_canonical_maps lookup table. From man 5 postconf:

sender_canonical_maps (default: empty)
       Optional address mapping lookup tables for envelope and  header  sender
       addresses.   The  table  format  and  lookups are documented in canoni‐
       cal(5).

```
   Example: you want to rewrite the SENDER address  "user@ugly.domain"  to
   "user@pretty.domain", while still being able to send mail to the RECIP‐
   IENT address "user@ugly.domain".

   Note: $sender_canonical_maps is processed before $canonical_maps.

   Example:

   sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a header where you put "From: Toto toto < toto@toto.com >" (without spaces, but the interface remove the contents of <   >).

To change it in default setting, you should do this not in PHP, but in your MTA. Rewrite the from address to what you want.